# Returning and echoing $this?

Tags: php, oop, magento-1.7

I just started to learn Magento and I find it intriguing how it executes methods, for instance,

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('blablabla') ?>
```

`$this` seems to be the object identifier, which we normally would get an error as `$this` a predefined variable in PHP.

So, I am testing a class whether I can do the same like Magento's. My test,

```
class boo
{

    function getChildHtml()
    {
        return "hello world!";
    }

    function getMethod()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml();
    }   

}

$boo = new boo();
echo $boo->getMethod();
// result: hello world!

$this = new boo();
echo $this->getMethod();
//Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this
```

Can anyone show me how I can do it like the way Magento does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This look like a type of MVC style approach.

Here's a quick example that shows you how to use the `$this` approach in view files.

views.php:

```
<?php

class boo
{
    public $content;

    public function do_something()
    {
        return date("Y-m-d");
    }

    public function load($file)
    {
        ob_start();
        require($file);
        $this->content = ob_get_clean();
        echo $this->content;
    }
}

$boo = new boo();
$boo->load('test.php');
```

test.php:

```
<?php echo $this->do_something(); ?>
```

To be honest I'm not sure if need to do the output buffering or not, it's just a quick example.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to re-assign the `$this` variable by design. The `$this` variable always dynamically references the class we're currently inside of. In Magento or generally in Zend Framework, the `$this` object in phtml files references the view object.

More on that:
[How $this works in .phtml files in zend framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840298/how-this-works-in-phtml-files-in-zend-framework)